# Are there supported ways to deliver a multi-language voice-heavy app for iOS and Android?

Tags: android, ios, localization, google-play, app-store

Are there features within App Store and/or Google Play to support locale specific app files?

I want to keep download size down, and I have content that is locale specific.

Details: I have an game app with a **lot** of spoken audio. For one language, say English, it's not a big deal. When I want to deliver it via App Store and Google Play with multiple languages, the app size goes up significantly. I'd prefer to have some automatic way to default the audio download to the locale of the downloader.